# Format descriptors for array printing

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to print an integer array of dimension `(n, m)` in Fortran (95). When I use the following technique to format the output, it works:

```f95
write (*, '(nIw)') array
```

Somehow, it automatically shifts each row to the next line, using the same format descriptor for each. (?)

But in this case, why doesn't it work?

```f95
    write (*, 100) array
100 FORMAT('nIw')
```

What is different in these two approaches?

Comment: What do you think the edit descriptor nIw does?

Comment: Please show the actual code and the actual output that the code produced with your compiler. Your two approaches are completely equivalent. I will vote to close as "not reproducible" until that.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sorry, that would be `array`. I made an error while copying code.

Comment: I made a mistake in interpreting how edit descriptors are written in a `format` statement. @Federico Perini's answer solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please understand that if you showed the actual input, someone would probably spotted the problem straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FORMAT 100` is not properly written: you're trying to print a string, "`nIw`", instead of a number. Check out this example:

```
program print_integer
      implicit none

      character(*), parameter :: fmt_int = '(10I3)'

      integer :: j,array(10) = [(j,j=1,10)]


      write(*,fmt_int) array
      write(*,'(10I3)') array
      write(*,    100) array
      write(*,    200) array   ! WRONG FORMAT


      100 format(10I3)
      200 format('10I3')

end program print_integer
```

Comment: Thanks, that was silly of me, I interpreted the instructions in the book wrong.